# My webpage is showing extra table information outside the loop in ruby on rails while retrieving rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rails-activerecord

Please help me.
My code is

```
<%= Region.find(:all).each do |myregion| %>
  <li><a href="#" data-text="<%= t(myregion.slug) %>"><%= t(myregion.name) %></a></li>
```

Database has only two records: japan and korea.But, it shows other information outside the loop like [#, #]... i dont want these information on my website unnecessarily.

How to remove this?

Comment: Try to write *Region.all.each*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of

```
 <%= Region.find(:all).each do |myregion| %>
```

use

```
<% Region.find(:all).each do |myregion| %>

<%= %> # render string
<%  %> # execute code
```